# How to get the insert ID after insert using the PDO transactino in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

Before making `commit`, how to get the `row ID` after insert using transaction in PHP

Comment: He said he's using PDO but anyone stumbling across this may find the MySQLi version helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$qry = $con->prepare("/* query */");
$con->beginTransaction();
$qry->execute();
    $last_id = $con->lastInsertId();    // This
$con->commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Request your pdo object to give last id inserted:

```
$lastId = $pdoObject->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: `$pdoObject = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'username', 'password');`